# What will happen if the target file has been changed between calls of InternetReadFile?

Tags: winapi, wininet

I'm trying to download the contents of a file on Internet which will be updated every 5 seconds.
I'm using `InternetReadFile()` function of WinINet, after having opened Internet handles with `InternetOpen()` and `InternetOpenUrl()`.
Since the file is quite large, I need to call `InternetReadFile()` multiple times to download the entire file. But, what will happen if that file has been updated between calls of `InternetReadFile()`?

Will I get a file with parts of old file and parts of updated file?

Comment: *Will I get a file with parts of old file and parts of updated file?* Yes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what file would both be updated every 5 seconds and be so large that there would be no chance of downloading it in time?! That sounds very shortsighted on the server authors's part...

Comment: @andlabs It's not a such large file, I just don't want to allocate a buffer with tens or sometimes hundreds of thousands of bytes....

Comment: Ah, that's all right then.